# Действие при зажатии кнопки андроид

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-button, android-on-click

как увеличивать определенную переменную при одиночном нажатии и при зажатии клавиши??? принцип должен быть как например с клавишами увеличения и уменьшения громкости на смартфонах, то есть один раз нажали громкость уменьшилась на одно деление, зажали кнопку громкость поползла вниз или вверх, пока полностью не выключилась. в этом коде у меня получается только раз нажать для выполнения  функции, а если долго нажимать на кнопку приблизительно 2-4секунды то ничего не происходит. возможно я не совсем доходчиво объяснил проблему если что в комментариях спрашивайте.

```
   findViewById(R.id.up).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     long currTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: lastAction = currTime;
     if (simpleValue <=20 && simpleValue > 0)
     {
     simpleValue = simpleValue - 2;
     }
     else
     {
     simpleValue = simpleValue - 20;
     }
     break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: if (currTime - lastAction >= REPEAT_INTERVAL) {
     lastAction = currTime;
     if (simpleValue <=20 && simpleValue > 0)
     {
     simpleValue = simpleValue - 2;
     }
     else
     {
     simpleValue = simpleValue - 20;
     }
     }
     break;
     }
     mEditor.putInt("value", simpleValue).apply();
     double dely = 1/(simpleValue*0.001*2);
     String formattedDouble = String.format("%.2f", dely);
     new_sec.setText("Переменная= " + formattedDouble);
     return true;
     }
     });
```

Comment: вам нужно изменить переменную при ACTION_UP, но если ACTION_DOWN, то изменить при ACTION_DOWN, но при ACTION_UP тогда чтобы не изменялось?

Comment: Чем метод setOnLongClickListener() вам не подходит?

Comment: я пробовал setOnLongClickListener() но он некорректно работает, мне нужно что бы я мог уменьшить эту переменную как громкость на телефоне по такому-же принципу, то есть один раз нажали на одно деление уменьшилось, зажали кнопку и ползунок пополз пока мы не отпустили кнопку, так же и здесь один раз нажали она уменьшилась на 20 один раз, зажали эту-же кнопку и эта переменная начала уменьшаться пока мы не отпустили кнопку

Comment: Понял, тогда попробуйте вернуть true в методе onTouch. В этом случае на сколько я знаю OnClickListener не должен срабатывать

Comment: я попробовал вернуть true в методе onTouch но теперь мне кажется что кнопка не отвечает на длительное нажатие, только на короткое, на сколько я понял что нам необходимо для одиночного нажатия и удержания создавать два слушателя но что бы они не пересекались

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подобных целей я использовал такой `OnTouchListener`:

```
public static class RepeateClick implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final long REPEAT_INTERVAL = 150L; // интервал повтора в миллисекундах
    private long lastAction = 0L;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        long currTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastAction = currTime;
                // код короткого нажатия
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (currTime - lastAction >= REPEAT_INTERVAL) {
                    lastAction = currTime;
                    // код действия при удержании
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Другой вариант: в `ACTION_DOWN` запускать таймер, который будет выполнять повторы, а в `ACTION_UP` его останавливать.

P.S. готовый код:

```
    findViewById(R.id.up).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private static final long REPEAT_INTERVAL = 150L; // интервал повтора в миллисекундах
        private long lastAction = 0L;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            long currTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    lastAction = currTime;
                    method();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (currTime - lastAction >= REPEAT_INTERVAL) {
                        lastAction = currTime;
                        method();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void method() {
            if (simpleValue <= 20 && simpleValue > 0) {
                simpleValue = simpleValue - 2;
            } else {
                simpleValue = simpleValue - 20;
            }
            mEditor.putInt("value", simpleValue).apply();
            double dely = 1 / (simpleValue * 0.001 * 2);
            String formattedDouble = String.format("%.2f", dely);
            new_sec.setText("Переменная= " + formattedDouble);
        }

    });
```

Comment: этот способ я конечно не видел но все-равно не помогло. работает только простое нажатие а если зажать кнопку то нету реакции, нужно будет еще попробовать второй способ

Comment: а может я не так его записал, ну то есть может есть какие-то подводные камни, например мне не очень понятно что такое 150L что это за единицы измерения??

Comment: `REPEAT_INTERVAL` - это время задержки между повторами в миллисекундах. `ACTION_MOVE` вызывается слишком часто, поэтому я ограничил повторы по времени. А Вы `OnClickListener` убрали? И `onTouch` должен вернуть `true`, иначе событие будет отдано другому обработчику. У меня этот код работает как надо.

Comment: я изменю код в вопросе так будет легче вам увидеть что у меня получилось и может я где-то ошибся

Comment: Смотрите P.S. Надеюсь просто скопипастить то уж сможете?

Comment: да что то я протупил в прошлый раз, все заработало и с прошлым примером, просто я вставлял REPEAT_INTERVAL в самое начало а не в сам обработчик

Comment: Дело не в этом. Вы `currTime` вынесли за пределы метода и он не менялся при срабатывании события, а следовательно условие в `ACTION_MOVE` всегда ложь.

Comment: а вот у меня еще один вопрос появился, можно ли уменьшив repeat_interval уменьшить скорость изменения переменной, потому-что сейчас она меняется быстрее чем мне нужно, если этот интервал измеряется в милисекундах то можно например установить 1000 миллисекунд??

Comment: Как раз для этого она и предназначена.